# Asp.net MVC recaptcha set language not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, recaptcha

I have create a recaptcha plugin and I wanted to change language from english to other languages (france, spanish or arabic) but it does not work it only change it if I visited (france, spanish or arabic) version of google and I have set:

```
<script>
     var RecaptchaOptions = {
     'theme': 'red',
     'lang': 'ar'
     };

</script>
```

in various places (before and after recaptcha) in my code but no luck my recaptcha html element:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" id="recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></div>
```

Comment: How are you changing language? Are you passing something on the query string of your application or stored in a cookie to change the Thread.CurrentCulture?

Comment: through javascript <script>
     var RecaptchaOptions = {
     'theme': 'red',
     'lang': 'ar'
     };

</script>

Answer (score 3):

Where you include the script on the page try appending hl={language} to the query string (as below).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=your_public_key&hl=fr" />
```

I found this answer on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/recaptcha/o-YdYJlnRVM

Hopefully this can help you, although be aware that the recaptcha should automatically translate so you may not need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello fellow human,**
just attach this code to end of view file:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=myCallBack&render=explicit&hl=pt" async defer>
</script>
```

- "pt", it's code language to change if you need the **language codes**:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/language